# ALTER USER in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to expire and lock accounts that have never been logged into EXCEPT SYS and RMAN (and accounts that begin with RMAN/SYS)

```
SELECT USERNAME 
FROM DBA_USERS 
WHERE (LAST_LOGIN IS NULL) 
AND not REGEXP_LIKE(USERNAME, '^SYS') 
ORDER BY LAST_LOGIN ASC;
```

This query returns rows that begin with SYS (yes I know I didn't specify RMAN but I am trying to figure out how to exclude SYS first)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT USERNAME 
FROM DBA_USERS 
WHERE (LAST_LOGIN IS NULL) 
  AND USERNAME NOT LIKE 'SYS%' 
ORDER BY LAST_LOGIN ASC;
```